# Why would I regress a vector on itself in a VAR?

Tags: regression, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I'm just working through an econometric paper by Bernanke / Blinder

http://drphilipshaw.com/Protected/The%20Federal%20Funds%20Rate%20and%20the%20Channels%20of%20Monetary%20Transmission.pdf

where in the very first formula, they make a regression of a vector onto itself:

$Y_{t} = b_{0}*Y_{t}+b_{1}*Y_{t-1}+C_{0}*P_{t}+C_{1}*P_{t-1}+u_{t}$

I don't understand why anyone would do that. Wouldn't that just make b0 an identity matrix and all other coefficient matrices zero?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The equation is part of a system. Equation (1) and (2) in the paper. And dependent var of (2) is $P_t$ with $Y_t$ on right hand side.

Comment: Isn't this question answered by equation (4) of the paper?